# Last year I took the bus to work. Since then I've taken the train

Tags: grammar, phrases

Just read this in a textbook (not written by natives I believe).

Is that correct, unambiguous? I would expect "Since then I have been taking the train".

Comment: It's correct, unambiguous and a common construction: fluent speakers would have no difficulty understanding the intent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both are fine.

When there is a difference between present perfect simple (I've taken) and present perfect continuous (I've been taking), the former focuses on the result, whereas the latter focuses on the fact that the process is ongoing.

For example:

> I've translated the report. It has taken me all morning (result is important)
>
> I've been translating the report all morning. (I'm not finished yet).

As you probably know, some verbs don't have an -ing form (e.g. to know), so you'd need to use the present perfect simple for these.

Otherwise (as is here the case) the present perfect simple and present perfect continuous can often be used interchangeably, with little difference in meaning.

Comment: So how do you know, in that example, whether it occurred once or repeatedly (taking the train)?

Comment: In both cases it occurred repeatedly. The difference between the two sentences is negligible.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I ask is that in the other question, the progressive was stated to be preferred. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/497584/which-tense-would-be-correct-in-this-context

Comment: Yeah, it might be prefered (that's not wrong), but the fact remains is that you can use both with little difference in meaning.

Comment: The difference between the two statements also comes from the fact that this one has something to compare it to. "Last year I took the bus" implies a repeated action, and the second sentence more strongly implies a repeated action here because it's contrasted with that first statement.

Comment: @JohnV This answer is incorrect in terms of what you're looking for. From the *have taken* form, it's *not* possible to know if the action has been repeated or not. All it conveys is that it has happened at least once. Also, in the *have been taking* form, it's *not* a given that the activity is unfinished. That sentence could be used to describe something that you *have* just finished doing. The actual meaning could only be determined from context.

Comment: @Jason Bassford: meh! In this case it very strongly implies the action was ongoing, so I disagree with your claim that the answer is incorrect. I do agree with your second point though (that an additional use of this tense is to describe something that you have just finished doing). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JamesHibbard "The baby's *been crying all morning*. But, thankfully, it seems *to have stopped now*." "I've *been working* on it all night, but I've had to take a break."

Comment: M'kay. Both correct sentences of course. My only point is that in a sentence such as "Last week my car broke down. Since then I've taken the train to work", there is a very strong implication (because of the context, if nothing else) that "taking the train to work" has occurred repeatedly.